# Go goroutines are not running

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Today, I learned about `buffered channels`. The issue I am facing understanding is, I am using WaitGroup's `Wait` function for all the goroutines to execute.

*But not all the goroutines are executing and the program ends before without waiting for all the goroutines to finish.*

Code:

```golang
func main() {
    
    // initializing a WaitGroup
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // adding 3 counts/buffer to the WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    
    fmt.Println("Start Goroutines")
    go responseSize("https://www.golangprograms.com", &wg)
    go responseSize("https://stackoverflow.com", &wg)
    go responseSize("https://coderwall.com", &wg)

    // wait for goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Terminating the main program")

}

// just prints the response size of the body returned 
func responseSize(url string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // schedule the Done() call when the goroutine is finished
    wg.Done()

    fmt.Println("Step1: ", url)
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println("Step2: ", url)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Step3: ", len(body))
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
wg.Done()
```

use

```
defer wg.Done()
```

The way it is written, your goroutines signal that the work is gone when they start running, not when they end, allowing the main goroutine to continue and exit.

Comment: Oh fish, I understood the reason now. Thanks! I'll approve the answer in 10 mins.